# C: Printing every possible string starting with 'a', recursive functions

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

I want to create a program that prints every possible string starting with the character 'a' with an arbitrary maximum length. For this example we'll use a maximum length of 4. A recursive function seemed like a good way to handle this however I'm really confused now as to why the recursive function won't print for example "ab"? It seems like the loop doesn't continue after recursive is called again.

```
int main () 
{
    char *str = malloc(5* sizeof(char));
    str[0] = 'a';
    recursive(str, 1);
}

void recursive(char *string, int index) 
{
    // Max length of 4
    if (index > 3)
        return;

    for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'j'; c++) 
    {
        string[index] = c;
        printf("str: %s\n", string);

        recursive(string, index + 1);   
    }
}
```

While the result is close to what I want, notice that there's no "ab", "ac", "abc", "acb", basically any string of length 2 or 3 (other than aa/aaa). Every combination of length 4 (maximum) is getting printed though.

[image: the result]

Any way to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: You have `aabj` and `aacj` printed at least twice, so there's something else you have to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your algorithm or recursion. The only thing you need is to shorten your string after your recursion step finishes (strings are ASCIIZ in C).

The fix is simple: you need to ensure there are zeroes in your allocated memory block, which is done by clearing its contents using `memset` (memory block whose pointer is returned by `malloc` contains garbage).

```
int main () 
{
    size_t size = 5;
    char* str = (char*)malloc(size);
    memset(str, 0, size);
    str[0] = 'a';
    recursive(str, 1);
}
```

And then in your loop:

```
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'j'; c++)
{
    string[index] = c;
    printf("str: %s\n", string);

    recursive(string, index + 1);

    string[index] = 0; // <-- revert last letter to zero
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much for your answer, it seems to work perfectly! I see you also changed my main function, although I don't get why?

Comment: You need to be sure there are zeroes in the memory block returned by `malloc`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Does memset(str, 0, size); make sure that there's only 0s? What happens if that's not the case? Also, how come there's duplications in my results?

Comment: Yes, after `memset` is called you can be sure your memory block contains only zeroes. Whan duplicates do you mean? When you revert your last letter to zero, then you get no duplicates. The duplicate you see on the screenshot is an outcome of not clearing last letter after recursion step finishes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help